# JMeter not recording download scenario

Tags: jmeter

I am testing a web-portal and using jmeter for the performance testing.
Now i am able to record all the things, but the web-portal has an option to download files and when i click on download the process of downloading starts and jmeter is not recording
this scenario.

So how can i make jmeter to record this download scenario?

Answer (score 2):

This should be an answer:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file

View I got is different. Old Version maybe.. Here are images to what I got.  Anyway it works! Thanks!

[image: Path to element]

[image: Save responses to a file:]

Answer (score 1):

Create a new request for the file you want to download. In this request, point it directly to the file you want to download and make sure you click "retrieve embedded resources" at the bottom of the page.