# Does Jmeter record any file download/save files on my desktop?

Tags: jmeter

I have an application where some report files (xls type) are being generated.
So I want to download them first and than want to save them on my desktop folder.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: "The Apache JMeter™ desktop application is open source software, a 100% pure Java application designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance." (https://jmeter.apache.org/index.html) Maybe JMeter is not the right tool for your task.

Answer (score 1):

...Next time please try to search across the existent questions and answers first:

- [JMeter - File upload and file download scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676249/jmeter-file-upload-and-file-download-scenario?rq=1)
- [How to save a file with dynamic value in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470557/how-to-save-a-file-with-dynamic-value-in-jmeter?rq=1)
- [JMeter not recording download scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983936/jmeter-not-recording-download-scenario?rq=1)